# How to if-let on a generic protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have a protocol with an associatedtype:

```
protocol FormInputType {
  associatedtype Input
  var field: Input! { get set }
}
```

I then have a number of classes that implement this (and also derive from a base class) with different types of input (text field, text views etc etc).

I have extended this protocol for those different types for resigning first responder, or to set placeholders, or whatever else:

```
extension FormInputType where Self.Input == UIResponder
extension FormInputType where Self.Input == UITextView
```

I then have a class that has an array of these. Example:

```
let array: [FormField] = [InputTextView(), InputTextField(), InputTextField()]
```

How can I in my other class call the methods on the `FormInputType` extension? It seems I can't `if let` on generic constraints. How can I iterate through the array to see if any of them match a constraint?

More information:

```
class FormField
{
}

class InputTextView: FormField, FormInputType {
  var field: UITextView!
}
class InputTextField: FormField, FormInputType {
  var field: UITextField!
}
```

How can I then do something like a for loop, checking if a particular field conforms to FormInputType where `Input == UIResponder` (for example), similar to how you can create a function and do `<T: FormInputType where T.Input == UIResponder>`

Comment: What is `InputTextView`? Please show the real array. How it is defined and how it is populated. Finally what did you write inside your 2 extensions?

Comment: @appzYourLife There is too much code to copy/paste everything, but here's the general style and players involved.

Comment: You might need some [type erasure](https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/) here...

Answer (score 0):

You must cast it to the specific class that implements the `FormInputType` protocol. This is a drawback of the static type system that Swift adopts.

If you write this, Swift doesn't know what type `FormInputType.Input` is:

```
for item in array {
    if let item = item as? FormInputType { // Compiler error. What type is `field`?

    }
}
```

Instead, cast it the specific class that conforms to the protocol:

```
for item in array {
    switch item {
    case let item as InputTextView:
        // Now we are sure that `field` is UITextView
    case let item as InputTextField:
        // Now we are sure that `field` is UITextField
    default:
        // Unknown type
    }
}
```